# adding a subview displaying front facing camera in iphone

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to add a mirro subview using the front facing camera using the iphone. How do I do that? As I am new to iphone programming, I have some difficulty in using and configuring the UIImagePickerViewController. This is what I have so far. But I am not quite sure how to set up the delegate. And is it correct to use UIView instead of UIImageView?

my .h file

```
@interface myViewController  : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    //front facing camera view
    UIImagePickerController *imageCameraController;
    IBOutlet UIView *viewFrontFacingCamera;
}
```

and implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]&&[UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]){
        imageCameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imageCameraController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        imageCameraController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        imageCameraController.delegate=viewFrontFacingCamera????
        viewFrontFacingCamera =imageCameraController.view;
    }
}
```

Thanks!